# Fast algorithm for counting the number of acyclic paths on a directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

In short, I need a **fast** algorithm to count how many acyclic paths are there in a simple directed graph.

By *simple* graph I mean one without self loops or multiple edges.
A *path* can start from any node and must end on a node that has no outgoing edges.  A path is *acyclic* if no edge occurs twice in it.

My graphs (empirical datasets) have only between 20-160 nodes, however, some of them have many cycles in them, therefore there will be a very large number of paths, and my naive approach is simply not fast enough for some of the graph I have.

What I'm doing currently is "descending" along all possible edges using a recursive function, while keeping track of which nodes I have already visited (and avoiding them).  The fastest solution I have so far was written in C++, and uses std::bitset argument in the recursive function to keep track of which nodes were already visited (visited nodes are marked by bit 1).  This program runs on the sample dataset in 1-2 minutes (depending on computer speed).  With other datasets it takes more than a day to run, or apparently much longer.

The sample dataset: http://pastie.org/1763781
(each line is an edge-pair)

Solution for the sample dataset (first number is the node I'm starting from, second number is the path-count starting from that node, last number is the total path count):
http://pastie.org/1763790

*Please let me know if you have ideas about algorithms with a better complexity.  I'm also interested in approximate solutions (estimating the number of paths with some Monte Carlo approach).  Eventually I'll also want to measure the average path length.*

Note: Same question previously posted on [stackoverlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569256/fast-algorithm-for-counting-the-number-of-acyclic-paths-on-a-directed-graph), hope this is not against the rules.  Later realized the question has more to do with maths.

Comment: An easy bad upper bound for an undirected connected graph $G$ is given by ${n\choose 2}c$ where $c$ is the complexity (number of spanning trees) of $G$ and where $G$ has $n$ vertices. The number 
$c$ is easy to compute by Kirhoff's theorem.

Comment: This is not really an answer, I'm still thinking about it... But perhaps one way to make your algorithm faster is to implement it iteratively instead of recursively. This will remove many function calls, and should be a bit nicer in the memory. I don't really think there is another way than bruteforce enumeration in this case :-/

Answer (score -1):

I believe the magical words are "topological sort".

Comment: Igor, topological sort is only for acyclic graphs, but even there I'm not completely sure how it helps in counting the number of paths.  Can you elaborate please?

Comment: To clarify, my graphs have many cycles in them, but I need to count acyclic paths (i.e. paths with no repeating nodes).